# cloud_sql_proxy gives "error reading config"... how do I fix this?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have gcloud working in power shell:

```
> gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 375.0.0
bq 2.0.74
core 2022.02.25
gsutil 5.6
```

I've been trying to follow these directions to get my Sql Management Studio to connect to a Google SQL service:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-proxy#start-proxy

But I get this error:

```
PS C:\gcloud_stuff> ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<my instance connection>=tcp:1433
2022/03/06 02:02:51 GcloudConfig: error reading config: exit status 1; stderr was:
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
2022/03/06 02:02:51 google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?  (I am new to Google Cloud)

Comment: Can you try running `gcloud auth application-default login`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a local set of credentials.

You can either run `gcloud auth login` and try again. Or you can create a service account key and pass it to the proxy with the `-credentials_file` flag. See the [Proxy docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#credentials) for details.

Comment: I ended up setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS which did the trick.